# Email is sending but not receiving when use no authentication

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am sending email using

```
public void sendEmail(String fromEmailAddr, String toEmailAddr,String subject, String emailBody) {  

    String host = "xxx";    
    final String user = "user";
    final String password = "password";

    // Get system properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    // Setup mail server
     properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
     properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");


     // Get the default Session object.
     Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);

    try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         // Set From: header field of the header.
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmailAddr));

         // Set To: header field of the header.
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmailAddr));

         // Set Subject: header field
         message.setSubject(subject);

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText(emailBody);

         // Send message
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

When i try to send email using above code then it comes to message `Sent message successfully....` but i got no email. On the other hand if i use authentication then i got the email

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

 Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);
                }
        });
```

Why ? Is it necessary to provide userName and password for host ? Can i send email by just specifying host, no username and password provided ?

Thanks

Comment: In the first case, did you see sent email in the email client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the port number might be the issue.

Try changing `properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");`

to `properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");`.

Further you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16441285/1471314).

Comment: Thanks. But changing port isn't working. I get the error `Could not connect to SMTP host: xx.xx.xx.xx, port: 587;`. Also in the link gmail is used. Gmail is fine. But i am not using Gmail.

Comment: That port is for gmail only. Which host are you using ?

Comment: On the other hand, you will need to specify the authentication for the host you are using if you want your emails to get transported.

Comment: I am using my company server. Actually the host that i am using is also use by another program to send email, but that program is on C#. In C# there is no password, you just specify the host and it is sending emails, but when i am using the same host on Java, then i need to specify user and password. I know java is not C# :) but this is the reason why i am asking is it necessary to specify authentication to send emails in Java :)

Comment: See, what i know is, for whichever host you are using, u need to authenticate using some account in order to transport the email. Else, you will get some exceptions regarding authentication.  Secondly, if you are using your company's network then try putting host as `smtp.xyz.com`, port number `587` and specify the protocol as `smtp`. Then, authenticate with your account details. I guess this will do the trick.

Comment: ` Secondly, if you are using your company network then try putting host as smtp.xyz.com, port number 587 and specify the protocol as smtp. Then, authenticate with your account details. I guess this will do the trick. ` This is working. I already said in my post that if i use authentication then i am receiving emails. I use my account credentials that company gave to me. Anyways thanks for your help buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the mail server you're using.

For example, some mail servers will let you send mail to anyone in the same company without authentication, but authentication is needed to send mail outside of the company.  In the latter case, if you send the mail without authenticating, the mail server may accept the message and return a "mailer-daemon" failure message, or might just throw the message away.

Also, see this list of [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Comment: I think there is second case happening `mail server may accept the message and return a "mailer-daemon" failure message, or might just throw the message away.` Because i get no exception. The code prints `"Sent message successfully...."` and that's it. But i get no email ... Anyways thanks for explaining :)

Comment: You'll probably need to look at the logs in the mail server to figure out what it did with the message.